# When using react-leaflet, for Marker it shows <img src=[object Module]>

Tags: leaflet, markers, react

When using react-leaflet with create-react-app, for Marker it shows <img src=[object Module]> in console after changing the default icon as given in here - [https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/453#issuecomment-541142178](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/453#issuecomment-541142178https://)
. Hence I am unable to view the marker Icon on Map.

```
delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
    iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
    shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
});
return (
    <>
        <Marker position={location}> </Marker>
    </>
)
```

Comment: Since this is as workaround for a bug in react-leaflet, GIS SE site is not the right place to resolve the problem.

Comment: @TomazicM Can you please explain in detail what you mean by "workaround" exactly? It would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: According to the provided link in your question all those code snippets are workarounds for problem in react-leaflet when using create-react-app webpack config. Let me cite from the page: "When it will work "out of the box"? Strange prop deleteing and monkey patching of "mergeOptions' - smells bad (("

Comment: I got your point @TomazicM . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-- src={require('../images/'+image_name+'.png')}`
use `-- src={require('../images/'+image_name+'.png').default}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import carLogo from '../../assets/car-icon.png'

const carIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: carLogo,
    iconRetinaUrl: carLogo,
    iconSize: [60, 55],
    shadowSize: [50, 64],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
})
```

Comment: Welcom on GIS.stackexchange! could you please add some text to support your code ? It will improve the overall quality of your answer